# why my window has been closed, but the application sometimes is still running background

Tags: c++, windows

main.cpp:

```
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd,
    UINT msgID,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam)
{
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msgID, wParam, lParam);
}


int CALLBACK WinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hIns,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPreIns,
    _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASS wc = { 0 };
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hIns;
    wc.hIcon = NULL;
    wc.hCursor = NULL;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = "MAINWINDOW";

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow("MAINWINDOW",
        "mainwindow",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        100, 100, 500, 500,
        NULL, NULL, hIns, NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);

    MSG nMsg = { 0 };
    while (GetMessage(&nMsg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&nMsg);
        DispatchMessage(&nMsg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I think that if I closed window, the application should also be closed too.
However, sometimes it worked as I thought, and sometimes the window is closed but the application was still running.
Why and how to make sure that the application is definitely exited after I close the window

Comment: *I think that if I closed window, the application should also be closed too* -- No.  You still have to call the requisite function(s) to break out of the message loop.  Also, where did you get that sample Window procedure from?  It should look something [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-close).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I got this sample from my school classes. I thought that DefWindowProc function should have done everything for me, including close window then exit the message loop and return the main

Comment: Use the documented approach at the link.  Nowhere is it documented that `WM_QUIT` is automatically posted to the message loop, so as to stop the loop from running.  That's what `PostQuitMessage` is all about.  Second, I suggest you use Windows API *books*, such as the ones that Charles Petzold has authored, and not rely on what a classroom is telling you.  Windows API programming is complex as it is, and erroneous or missing information will just lead to a lot of wasted time in getting things correct.

Comment: @ PaulMcKenzie Got it, thank you very much